# Automapper Instance version with Initialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am currently using `AutoMapper` in my ASP.Net MVC site to map ViewModels to DTO's and vice versa.
We are currently seeing performance issues when we setup an instance of the mapper, presumably because we are adding the profile each time. The code for my mapper is given below:

```
public class MyMapper
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public MyMapper(Profile profile)
    {

        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddMemberConfiguration();
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        });
        _mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
    }

    public IMapper Mapper {get; set;} 
}
```

So when I require mappings, I pass in the `Profile` that I need to the MyMapper wrapper, and it sets up the configuration, and gives me a mapper with that `Profile`. This is great, as I use multiple profiles to allow different mappings for the same types.

So I can see I performance hit everytime I create a `MyMapper` object, presumably as `AutoMapper` is doing all of the configuration each time. When I looked online, it suggests that I use the `Mapper.Initialize()` call so that the configuration is only done once. My issue is that this is on the `static` version of `AutoMapper`, not the instance version.

Does anyone have any example of how to setup the configuration via profiles and instance versions of `Automapper`, and do the configuration only once?

If not, what are my thread safe options?

- Dependency Injection of the `Configuration` into my mapper when required?
- Static versions of the `Configuration` objects that can be shared from `Global.asax`?

Would the answer given in [Switch between configurations in AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734675/switch-between-configurations-in-automapper) be suitable and thread safe?